# How can I enable CORS on Django REST Framework

Tags: python, django, cors, django-rest-framework, middleware

How can I enable CORS on my Django REST Framework?
the [reference](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/topics/ajax-csrf-cors/) doesn't help much, it says that I can do by a middleware, but how can I do that?

Comment: Django REST has package django-cors-headers, `settings..py` can have CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST to set Access-Control-Allow-Origin. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49520118/1548275

Answer (score 363, accepted):

The link you referenced in your question recommends using [`django-cors-headers`](https://github.com/ottoyiu/django-cors-headers/), whose [documentation](https://github.com/ottoyiu/django-cors-headers/#setup) says to install the library

```
python -m pip install django-cors-headers
```

and then add it to your installed apps:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    ...
    'corsheaders',
    ...
)
```

You will also need to add a middleware class to listen in on responses:

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    ...,
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    ...,
]
```

and specify domains for CORS, e.g.:

```
CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS = [
    'http://localhost:3030',
]
```

Please browse [the configuration section](https://github.com/ottoyiu/django-cors-headers/#configuration) of its documentation, paying particular attention to the various `CORS_ORIGIN_` settings. You'll need to set some of those based on your needs.

Comment: do you know any other way to do that, without the need to install a new dependency? I am trying to create a middleware class now

Comment: @JulioMarins, why would you write your own version when this is readily available and easily installable, with 12 releases, 21 contributors, over 800 stars and over 100 forks?

Comment: You have a point indeed, but since the only need for a simple CORS is a header `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` I don't see why load a whole thing, I will put another way to do this in your answer so both methods can be available. reference: [link(]http://enable-cors.org/server.html)

Comment: @JulioMarins, that would be the sledgehammer approach. If you look at the configuration link I provided you'll see that `django-cors-headers` is much more flexible than that. If you would prefer to create your own class, be my guest. But I'd be using that library.

Comment: @Chris I think you should add [CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST](https://github.com/ottoyiu/django-cors-headers/#cors_origin_whitelist) so that you whitelist the calling host.

Comment: This article gives example to allow CORS without extra package: https://www.techiediaries.com/django-cors/

Comment: @nos, that blog post doesn't improve much on [Julio's existing answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35761458/354577), which has the benefit of being fully contained on Stack Overflow and therefore not subject to link rot.

Comment: It doesn't support Django version < 1.11

Comment: @Viraj, even _Django_ doesn't support Django version < 1.11 anymore. Version 1.10 stopped receiving extended support on December 2, 2017. If you're still using 1.10 or earlier I urge you to upgrade. See https://www.djangoproject.com/download/#supported-versions

Comment: @Viraj, but note that support for earlier versions of Django [was](https://github.com/ottoyiu/django-cors-headers/blob/master/HISTORY.rst#250-2019-03-05) recently [removed](https://github.com/ottoyiu/django-cors-headers/commit/6a28e29774d2a25ed736163cc239449ff9448a53) from `django-cors-headers`. Again, a _much better_ solution is to upgrade Django, but if you're stuck on 1.8, 1.9, or 1.10 and upgrading is impossible you could use [`django-cors-headers` version 2.4.1](https://github.com/ottoyiu/django-cors-headers/releases/tag/2.4.1).

Comment: Do I need to add `CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS` as well (https://github.com/adamchainz/django-cors-headers#csrf-integration)

Comment: If the above steps didn't help - Make sure you added the trailing comma.

Comment: I need some clarification: I am having a Django web app in which I set my react app in a folder inside the Django project folder. when I make a request to get data from Django server (127.0.0.1:8000/api/resource) Postgres database, from React app localhost:3000, even after setting all the required parameters in my settings.py, I still get the following error: ....has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. I have even tried all the settings given on this stack page...still not getting data...

Comment: This worked for us. Just that we were running the application on a docker container, instead of installing `django-cors-headers` via the above command, we had to have `django-cors-headers==3.13.0` in requirements.txt which is installed when building the container.

Answer (score 154):

```
python -m pip install django-cors-headers
```

and then add it to your installed apps:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...
    'corsheaders',
    ...
]
```

You will also need to add a middleware class to listen in on responses:

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    ...,
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    ...,
]

CORS_ALLOW_ALL_ORIGINS = True # If this is used then `CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS` will not have any effect
CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = True
CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS = [
    'http://localhost:3030',
] # If this is used, then not need to use `CORS_ALLOW_ALL_ORIGINS = True`
CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGIN_REGEXES = [
    'http://localhost:3030',
]
```

more details: https://github.com/ottoyiu/django-cors-headers/#configuration

read the official documentation can resolve almost all problem

Comment: Adding the four lines you added to @Chris's answer was necessary for this to work for me.

Comment: Why is `CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True`, but `CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST` is still set? [The docs](https://github.com/ottoyiu/django-cors-headers/#cors_origin_allow_all) seem to make it seems like this is not required and seems to be confusing for the answer here.

Comment: CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL
If True, the whitelist will not be used and all origins will be accepted.

Comment: Also keep in mind `'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',` needs to be rather at the top of the list, otherwise the connection may be rejected prior to getting to it.

Comment: CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True, this did the trick.

Comment: How do I use with a Django version 2.2 ???

Answer (score 25):

You can do by using a custom middleware, even though knowing that the best option is using the tested approach of the package `django-cors-headers`. With that said, here is the solution:

create the following structure and files:

-- *`myapp/middleware/__init__.py`*

```
from corsMiddleware import corsMiddleware
```

-- *`myapp/middleware/corsMiddleware.py`*

```
class corsMiddleware(object):
    def process_response(self, req, resp):
        resp["Access-Control-Allow-Origin"] = "*"
        return resp
```

add to `settings.py` the marked line:

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    "django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware",

    # Now we add here our custom middleware
     'app_name.middleware.corsMiddleware' <---- this line
)
```

Comment: Thanks Julio! Your middleware code should be updated with @masnun code sample. Also, the import doesn't work for me, importing from . fixes the issue: 

`from . import corsMiddleware`

Comment: What about this? 'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
No need to add?

Answer (score 19):

In case anyone is getting back to this question and deciding to write their own middleware, this is a code sample for Django's new style middleware -

```
class CORSMiddleware(object):
    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response

    def __call__(self, request):
        response = self.get_response(request)
        response["Access-Control-Allow-Origin"] = "*"

        return response
```

Answer (score 14):

For Django versions > 1.10, according to the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/http/middleware/), a custom MIDDLEWARE can be written as a function, let's say in the file: `yourproject/middleware.py` (as a sibling of `settings.py`):

```
def open_access_middleware(get_response):
    def middleware(request):
        response = get_response(request)
        response["Access-Control-Allow-Origin"] = "*"
        response["Access-Control-Allow-Headers"] = "*"
        return response
    return middleware
```

and finally, add the python path of this function (w.r.t. the root of your project) to the MIDDLEWARE list in your project's `settings.py`:

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
  .
  .
  'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
  'yourproject.middleware.open_access_middleware'
]
```

Easy peasy!

Comment: The approach posted before uses MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES and not MIDDLEWARE. This technique works so the downvote was uncalled for :) @JulioMarins

Comment: dude, the solution is the same. You're arguing about implementation on the Django version. Your code is also with wrong indentation on `open_access_middleware`.

Answer (score 13):

**Updated 2021** for all those who have the latest version of Django v3.x.x, The steps to allow CORS from any origin are given below.

Step 1: Install required library

```
pip install django-cors-headers
```

Step 2: Then add in proper place in your **INSTALLED_APPS** in `settings.py` - after the `rest_framework` and before your application `myapp`

```
'rest_framework',
'corsheaders',
'myapp.apps.MyAppConfig',
```

Step 3: Allow the origins for your api (inside `settings.py`)

```
CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST = (
'http://localhost:3000',  # for localhost (REACT Default)
'http://192.168.10.45:3000', # for network
)
```

Comment: How will we add some regex to `CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST ` ?

Comment: @rickster you can use another setting `CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGIN_REGEXES`

Comment: ++ This (clearing cache) needs to be done after following these steps :)

https://stackoverflow.com/a/73322250/2233336

Answer (score 12):

**Updated 2022** and adding a new use case

When your using Axios POST with the option `withCredentials: true`, there are a few additional options to consider.

I used this specific case for authentification over Basic or/and Session login.

To Avoid error messages as:

> Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' header in the response is '' which must be 'true' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'. The credentials mode of requests initiated by the XMLHttpRequest is controlled by the withCredentials attribute.

And the above mentioned by others. I solved the issue in this way.

*[IP addresses are from my local example, have in mind to change it]*

setting.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...
    'rest_framework',
    'corsheaders',
    'rest_framework.authtoken',
    ...
]

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ["localhost","192.168.0.50"]

CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = True

CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST = (
    'http://localhost:3000',  # for localhost (REACT Default)
    'http://192.168.0.50:3000',  # for network 
    'http://localhost:8080',  # for localhost (Developlemt)
    'http://192.168.0.50:8080',  # for network (Development)
)

CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS = [
    'http://localhost:3000',  # for localhost (REACT Default)
    'http://192.168.0.50:3000',  # for network 
    'http://localhost:8080',  # for localhost (Developlemt)
    'http://192.168.0.50:8080',  # for network (Development)
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
...
'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
...
```

]

On the browser, the Axios request headers must be send and on the server site the headers must be permitted. If not, the error message will be.

> Request header field access-control-allow-origin is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.

Up to this moment play with the headers. You can add more headers if you need them, like:

```
CORS_ALLOW_HEADERS = [
'accept',
'accept-encoding',
'authorization',
'content-type',
'dnt',
'origin',
'user-agent',
'x-csrftoken',
'x-requested-with',
]
```

Cheers :)

Answer (score 9):

Below are the working steps without the need for any external modules:

**Step 1:** Create a module in your app.

E.g, lets assume we have an app called ***user_registration_app***. Explore user_registration_app and create a new file.

Lets call this as **custom_cors_middleware.py**

Paste the below Class definition:

```
class CustomCorsMiddleware:
    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response
        # One-time configuration and initialization.

    def __call__(self, request):
        # Code to be executed for each request before
        # the view (and later middleware) are called.

        response = self.get_response(request)
        response["Access-Control-Allow-Origin"] = "*"
        response["Access-Control-Allow-Headers"] = "*"

        # Code to be executed for each request/response after
        # the view is called.

        return response
```

**Step 2:** Register a middleware

In your projects settings.py file, add this line

*'user_registration_app.custom_cors_middleware.CustomCorsMiddleware'*

E.g:

```
  MIDDLEWARE = [
        'user_registration_app.custom_cors_middleware.CustomCorsMiddleware', # ADD THIS LINE BEFORE CommonMiddleware
         ...
        'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',

    ]
```

Remember to replace *user_registration_app* with the name of your app where you have created your custom_cors_middleware.py module.

You can now verify it will add the required response headers to all the views in the project!

Comment: Thank you! I was missing the Access-Control-Allow-Headers header.

Answer (score 5):

Well, I don't know guys but:

using here python 3.6 and django 2.2

Renaming MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES to MIDDLEWARE in settings.py worked.

Answer (score 5):

first install django package

```
pip install django-cors-headers
```

and add to apps in settings file

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
...
'corsheaders',
...
)
```

and then add cors middle ware to setting file

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
...,
'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
...,
]
```

and finally add cross orgin whitelist

```
#CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True
#CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = True
#CORS_ALLOW_HEADERS = ['*']
CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST = ('http://localhost:5000',)
```

that will solve cors error easily. happy coding

Answer (score 2):

After trying every suggested solution and nothing seemed to work. I finally fixed the issue after much frustration by clearing my browser cache...

Then the accepted answer works by using `django-cors-headers`.

Hope this helps someone else!

Shell command to clear the cache -

```
find . -name '*.pyc' -type f -delete && find . | grep -E "(/__pycache__$|\.pyc$|\.pyo$)" | xargs rm -rf
```

Answer (score 0):

> Django=2.2.12 django-cors-headers=3.2.1 djangorestframework=3.11.0

Follow the official instruction doesn't work

Finally use the old way to figure it out.

ADD:

```py
# proj/middlewares.py
from rest_framework.authentication import SessionAuthentication


class CsrfExemptSessionAuthentication(SessionAuthentication):

    def enforce_csrf(self, request):
        return  # To not perform the csrf check previously happening
```

```py
#proj/settings.py

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'proj.middlewares.CsrfExemptSessionAuthentication',
    ),
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me when placing corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware as the last bit of middleware