# Enabling CORS (Cross Origin Request) in Django

Tags: javascript, django, cors, cross-domain, overpass-api

I'm trying to make use of the overpass API http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API with a JavaScript XMLHttpRequest in a project running on Django but I keep getting the

```
 Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://www.google.com/accounts/ClientLogin. (Reason: CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' missing).
```

error. I get this error whether I'm using GET or POST, and from any other host, not just the overpass API.

I've installed django-cors-headers https://github.com/ottoyiu/django-cors-headers and followed the instructions there, putting 'corsheaders' into INSTALLED_APPS, and 'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware', 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware', into MIDDLEWARE_APPS and I've set

```
CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = true
```

in settings.py but nothing seems to work. I'm running it locally with

```
python manage.py runserver
```

but I'm also hosting it on openshift. Neither on of these work, they both give the error above.

Please let me know if I am missing anything here.

Comment: Are you getting this error in javascript that is trying to access openstreetmap/overpass?

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to use XmlHttpRequest in javascript.

Comment: That's obvious, doesn't answer the question. I'm asking if the site you are trying to enable CORS on is the site that is receiving requests from a different origin, or making requests to a different origin ... i.e. what is the URL that is getting the CORS error

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/35760943/10140011

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I enable CORS on Django REST Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35760943/how-can-i-enable-cors-on-django-rest-framework)

Answer (score 9):

I was having the same problem while trying to access my `Django Rest Framework` API hosted at [Heroku](https://www.heroku.com/) from my laptop (`localhost`). I am using `Django 1.10.2`, `DRF 3.4.7` and `python v3.4`.

I did `pip install django-cors-headers` (version 1.2.2) and configured it as the [docs](https://github.com/ottoyiu/django-cors-headers/#setup) say and then, the same error again :(

Keep searching for hours and then it hit me!

I did `pip install django-cors-middleware` (version 1.3.1) **without uninstalling** the `django-cors-headers` package. Also I didn't touch a thing in my `settings.py` file (it was configured as the `django-cors-headers` settings, although these two packages do not have many differences - the latter is a fork of the first).

Hit refresh (from localhost) and everything worked brilliantly!

I was now able to fetch data from `myapp.herokuapp.com` via [`jQuery`'s ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) method.

Comment: Why would this work? `django-cors-header` and `django-cors-middleware` do not depend on each other, so why would both be required?

It did work for me... but I'm confused why.

Comment: Actually, [`django-cors-middleware`](https://github.com/zestedesavoir/django-cors-middleware) is a fork of [`django-cors-headers`](https://github.com/adamchainz/django-cors-headers) (they mention it in their docs). So, that's how it works!

Comment: It doesn't work now, and the `django-cors-middleware` package has been merged into `django-cors-header` and is not maintained anymore.

Answer (score 5):

Remember to put the 'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware' in the top of your list, and also the 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware' is already a standard middleware

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
 ]
```

Answer (score 5):

CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = true

should be:

CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True

**T** capital letter for True.
Add additional required middleware

```
MIDDLEWARE = ['corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware', ]
```

and register 'corsheaders', to INSTALLED_APPS.

Comment: where to add CORS_ORGIN_ALLOW_ALL = TRUE.

Comment: @SULPHURICACID in your settings file