# Unable to post to a local server

Tags: angular, angular4-httpclient

I have a local `Angular4` application that's trying to post to a local django server. The problem is that I'm getting an error in the `http.post()`, but I don't think it's caused by an issue with the `CORS` (I'm managing to consume this api using an android app, and I don't see any error message in the Angular-app about the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`). Please find below my code:

```js
// get token from the server
const body = {
    username: 'username',
    password: 'password'
};
this.http.post('http://website.loc/api/auth/login/', body).subscribe(
    res => {
        console.log('res:' + res);
    },
    (err: HttpErrorResponse) => {
        console.log('err');
        console.dir(err);
    }
);
```

Here is the error I'm getting (it seems that it's not able to read the url):

```
{headers: Object, status: 0, statusText: "Unknown Error", url: null, ok: false, name: "HttpErrorResponse", message: "Http failure response for (unknown url): 0 Unknown Error", error: ProgressEvent error}
```

Any clue what might cause these kind of issues?

Comment: This is not a problem with Angular. It's error on your server. Please check that you return a valid JSON

Comment: @TheUnreal My server actually returns an object ({"auth_token":"value"}. Is there a way to make Angular accept this kind of output? Otherwise what should the output look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to find actual problem, It may cross domain issue. In android, native app not using a browser, it direct call web api and cross domain comes in browser only.

To find actual problem open developer tool and see console. If you see a message like cross domain or access denied. It's issue with cross domain. You have to configure cors in server. See in network activity for server response if there are not a cors issue. You can see actual service request and failure reason in network activity. In angular cache block you can not get actual problem which from configuration.

This may also issue with calling request from `https` to `non https` url. Browser not give permission to call ajax request from `https` to `non https` url.

To fix issue you have to find actual problem by developer console tool.

Comment: In the web developer tool `console` tab in firefox, I don't see any issue with the cross-domain. I will try to configure it later on the server and see if it fixes this problem. The website isn't working over https, just plain http.

Comment: You can try developer tool in chrome to get actual request and call same api with same params in postmen. If we get error, issue with server otherwise need to do something in angular, might be issue with intercepter if you are using

Comment: I've managed to call the same command with `curl` from the command-line, isn't that the same? Is there a way to make Angular more verbose about the error?

Comment: Try `fetch(url).then(res=>console.log(res)).catch(err=>console.error(err))`. If got error in console than issue with server conf or cors.

Comment: For future visitors, it was indeed the CORS that was causing the problem (although the error wasn't really explicit). Installing the adequate plugin in `Django` (See [cors](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35761088/2228912) solved my problem.