# Download file from server Angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, cors

I have a code to convert image to dataUrl

```
  convertToDataURLviaCanvas(url, outputFormat){
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  const img = new Image();
  img.crossOrigin = 'anonymous';
  img.onload = () => {
    let canvas = <HTMLCanvasElement> document.createElement('CANVAS'),
      ctx = canvas.getContext('2d'),
      dataURL;
    canvas.height = img.height;
    canvas.width = img.width;
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
    dataURL = canvas.toDataURL(outputFormat);
    resolve(dataURL);
    canvas = null;
  };
  img.src = url;
});
```

}

and a call this function

```
  this.convertToDataURLviaCanvas('https://www.google.de/images/srpr/logo11w.png', 'image/jpeg').then(imageData => {
  this.zip.file(image.file_name, imageData, {binary: true})

  this.zip.generateAsync({type: 'blob'}).then(content => {
        saveAs(content, 'images.zip');
      });
})
```

but there's an error with CORS

```
Failed to load https://www.google.de/images/srpr/logo11w.png: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:4200' is therefore not allowed access.
```

how can I fix it

Comment: This means that google.de server does not allow cross-origin requests, there is nothing that you can do here on client side.
If you want to use google services, go via APIs for developers

Comment: One hacky way is , for chrome you can download the CORS plugin
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi?hl=en

Comment: maybe is there another way to download files as archive?

Comment: Actually I need to download any number of files from backend as archive

Comment: what is you backend server? there in app-server you need to allow cross-origin requests

Comment: backend in Django and images stored in Amazon. and I get urls like this
"https://projects.s3.amazonaws.com/images/main-proj/1 - Copy.jpg"

Comment: You need to enable CORS on backend side,
Ask the backend guy to enable cross origin requests
they can follow this guide
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35760943/how-can-i-enable-cors-on-django-rest-framework/35761458

Comment: noway to implement it without it? maybe using proxy?

Comment: For testing purpose, You can install the above plugin, specifically for your browser

Comment: so not for testing the only vaariant is enable cors in backend side?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot download that file from the client code because the browser executing your code enforces, on behalf of the remote server, a no-cross-origin policy. You would have to apply changes to the Google server to be able to request the URL from the Google server.

What you can do is to have your very own backend download the file (using curl or whatever you have at hand), and either convert it there or loop it through to your frontend.

For instance, you could have a four-liner php script (or equivalent function in your backend technology) which you use for the loop-through:

```
<?php
header("Content-type: image/png");
echo(readfile("https://www.google.de/images/srpr/logo11w.png"));
?>
```