# No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' using django rest framework api

Tags: django

```
pip3 install django-cors-headers
Requirement already satisfied: django-cors-headers in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages
You are using pip version 9.0.1, however version 9.0.3 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

I've ran the following command:

I then set it in my INSTALLED_APPS respectivelikey like this:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'rest_framework',
    'corsheaders'
]
```

I then use it in middleware like this,

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware'
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]
```

I get following error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddlewaredjango'; 'corsheaders.middleware' is not a package

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 225, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 140, in inner_run
    handler = self.get_handler(*args, **options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/management/commands/runserver.py", line 27, in get_handler
    handler = super().get_handler(*args, **options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 65, in get_handler
    return get_internal_wsgi_application()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/servers/basehttp.py", line 49, in get_internal_wsgi_application
    ) from err
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: WSGI application 'instawork.wsgi.application' could not be loaded; Error importing module.
```

I've followed strict instructions, I'm currently using latest django framework too.

Answer (score 10):

You've missed comma, correct `MIDDLEWARE` is:

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]
```

Put `CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL=True` before `INSTALLED_APPS`. You can also specify hosts allowed for cors:

```
CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST = (
    'example.com',
)
```