# Rewriting services from Angular2 to Angular6 "Unexpected module 'HttpClientModule' declared by the module 'AppModule'

Tags: angular

I was trying to rewrite an service that worked just fine in Angular 2 and I have tried to rewrite with Angular 6.

Here's the service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { environment } from '../../environments/environment';
import {Cluster} from "./cluster";
import {map} from "rxjs/internal/operators";


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class FullDataService {
  private headers = new Headers({'Content-Type': 'application/json'});

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  getClusters() {
    const url = environment.apiUrl + '/api/v1/clusters';
    return this.http.get(url).pipe(map(res => <Cluster[]>res));
  }
}
```

Here's my app.models.ts:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { HttpClientModule, HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import * as $ from 'jquery';

import { ContentHeaderComponent} from './content-header/content-header.component';
import { ContentHeaderService} from './content-header/content-header.service';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { FullDataComponent } from './full-data/full-data.component';
import {FullDataService} from "./full-data/full-data.service";


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HttpClientModule,
    HomeComponent,
    ContentHeaderComponent,
    FullDataComponent,
    HttpClient,
   HttpClientModule
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule
  ],
  providers: [
    ContentHeaderService,
    FullDataService,
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#base-header .toggle-menu').click(function() {
        $('#base-sidebar').toggleClass('sidebar--hidden');
    });

    $('nav .sidebar__drawer > a').click(function() {
        $(this).parent().toggleClass('sidebar__drawer--opened');
    });
});
```

When I try to load my app in a browser I get this error in the console log:

```
compiler.js:215 Uncaught Error: Unexpected module 'HttpClientModule' declared by the module 'AppModule'. Please add a @Pipe/@Directive/@Component annotation.
    at syntaxError (compiler.js:215)
    at compiler.js:10524
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at CompileMetadataResolver.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.CompileMetadataResolver.getNgModuleMetadata (compiler.js:10506)
    at JitCompiler.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.JitCompiler._loadModules (compiler.js:22567)
    at JitCompiler.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.JitCompiler._compileModuleAndComponents (compiler.js:22548)
    at JitCompiler.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.JitCompiler.compileModuleAsync (compiler.js:22508)
    at CompilerImpl.push../node_modules/@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/fesm5/platform-browser-dynamic.js.CompilerImpl.compileModuleAsync (platform-browser-dynamic.js:143)
    at PlatformRef.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.PlatformRef.bootstrapModule (core.js:4199)
    at Object../src/main.ts (main.ts:11)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

UPDATE: Thanks for the help with there.  Now I am getting this error message when I service runs:

```
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

What's up with that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Remove **`HttpClientModule`**  from declarations , it should be under imports

```
 declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HttpClientModule,
    HomeComponent,
    ContentHeaderComponent,
    FullDataComponent,
    HttpClient,
    HttpClientModule // remove this from here
  ],
```

Comment: Can you tell me why I am getting "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource." errors now? :) Please.

Comment: you need to add CORS on server side

Comment: How do I do that? I'll try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35760943/how-can-i-enable-cors-on-django-rest-framework/35761458

Answer (score 1):

`HttpClientModule` should be added at imports array not declarations array.

**imports array** is for importing modules such as BrowserModule, AppRoutingModule, HttpClientModule

**declarations array** is for your AppComponent, HomeComponent, 
 ContentHeaderComponent, FullDataComponent, HttpClient

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HomeComponent,
    ContentHeaderComponent,
    FullDataComponent,
    HttpClient
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    HttpClientModule
  ],
  providers: [
    ContentHeaderService,
    FullDataService,
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```

**For** No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Try to add **header** in **server side**

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST');
header('Content-Type: application/json; Charset=UTF-8');
```