# How do I debug enabling CORS on my Django REST api

Tags: javascript, django, django-rest-framework, django-cors-headers

I'm trying to enable CORS on a simple django rest server.

I've followed the suggestions here [How can I enable CORS on Django REST Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35760943/how-can-i-enable-cors-on-django-rest-framework).

Specifically I have:

1) done

```
pip install django-cors-headers
```

2)

added corsheaders to my installed apps

3) 
added corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware at the top of the MIDDLEWARE section of my Django settings file

4) added

```
  CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True
  CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = True
  CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST = (
   'localhost:3000/radioDestinations/',
   'localhost:8080',
   )
```

but it's still not working.

When I send the request to the server (using a javascript fetch request) I get an error in the browser (...blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present...), but I don't get any output in the serve console.

How can I find out where the problem is?

Comment: What is the output of `curl -sD - -o /dev/null localhost:8080/` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`django-cors-headers` is reasonably fool-proof and your configuration seems correct to me.

There is however a gotcha I've had issues with, which might be your problem too: 
If you configure your server to serve static files without invoking Django / Python (pretty common, even on the built-in server), `django-cors-headers` cannot apply a CORS header to those responses. Depending on the browser, [this will cause problems with asynchronous requests, fonts and sometimes even images, video and audio.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS)

Comment: You're right the configuration turned out ot be correct. It worked fine after a restart.