# How to send POST request to Django API from ReactJS web app?

Tags: javascript, python, django, reactjs

I created a very simple Django API. It returns a fixed numeric value (just for testing purpose):

**views.py**

```
from django.http import HttpResponse

def index(request):
    return HttpResponse(0)
```

I also have a simple front-end developed using React JS. To develop the backend and front-end, I was using these two tutorials:

- ReactJS: https://mherman.org/blog/dockerizing-a-react-app/
- Django Python API: https://semaphoreci.com/community/tutorials/dockerizing-a-python-django-web-application

Now I want to send a POST request to Django API from ReactJS and pass `name` and `email` parameters. How can I do it?

This is my App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      fullname: "",
      emailaddress: ""
    };

    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(event) {
    const target = event.target;
    const value = target.type === "checkbox" ? target.checked : target.value;
    const name = target.name;

    this.setState({
      [name]: value
    });
  }

  handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log(this.state);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <header>
          <div className="container">
            <nav className="navbar">
              <div className="navbar-brand">
                <span className="navbar-item">Forms in React</span>
              </div>
            </nav>
          </div>
        </header>
        <div className="container">
          <div className="columns">
            <div className="column is-9">
              <form className="form" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                <div className="field">
                  <label className="label">Name</label>
                  <div className="control">
                    <input
                      className="input"
                      type="text"
                      name="fullname"
                      value={this.state.fullname}
                      onChange={this.handleChange}
                    />
                  </div>
                </div>

                <div className="field">
                  <label className="label">Email</label>
                  <div className="control">
                    <input
                      className="input"
                      type="email"
                      name="emailaddress"
                      value={this.state.emailaddress}
                      onChange={this.handleChange}
                    />
                  </div>
                </div>

                <div className="field">
                  <div className="control">
                    <input
                      type="submit"
                      value="Submit"
                      className="button is-primary"
                    />
                  </div>
                </div>
              </form>
            </div>
            <div className="column is-3">
              <pre>
                <code>
                  <p>Full Name: {this.state.fullname}</p>
                  <p>Email Address: {this.state.emailaddress}</p>
                </code>
              </pre>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: maybe something like this? https://www.techiediaries.com/react-ajax/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To send HTTP requests from React app, you have two main options.

Either use integrated Fetch API (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) or something like axios (https://github.com/axios/axios).

In order to get info from the form, trigger `onChange` on each input, and save the input state to component state.

```
onChange = (prop: any, value: string) => {
  this.setState({
    [prop]: value
  });
};
```

After that, here's an example using `fetch API`:

```js
const response = fetch("endpoint_url", {
  method: 'POST',
  body: JSON.stringify({
    this.state.name,
    this.state.email
    // Other body stuff
  }),
  headers: {
    'X-Api-Key': API_KEY,
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    // Other possible headers
  }
});
```

And in the end you need to parse the response as JSON using `const responseJson = response.json();`

Comment: Thanks. I tried this approach, but got error: `Access to fetch at 'http://localhost:8000/' from origin 'http://localhost' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.`

Comment: This is a Django related issue, not React. CORS, or `Cross origin resource sharing` is a security feature which blocks some unauthorized request. In order to solve it, you must add allow header to the Django API and authorize the domain from which you are triggering the request. In this case probably `localhost`or any other if it's a remote domain.

Comment: @ScalaBoy You need to allow `Cross Origin Resource Sharing` on your API (Django in your case)

Comment: How do I solve it? I followed this approach, but still the code fails with CORS error https://github.com/crs4/ome_seadragon/wiki/Enable-Django-CORS-(Cross-Origin-Resource-Sharing)-Headers-configuration. and this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35760943/how-can-i-enable-cors-on-django-rest-framework

Comment: It's a completely different question, try asking it on Django subforums, I haven't been working with Django directly.

Comment: install django-cors-headers from pip and add it to installed apps after which you must add cors whitelist to settings.py, in the whitelist you have to add the locahost:3000 to whitelist it and allow it to make post request