# How to pass JsonWebToken(JWT) through AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, django-rest-framework, jwt

I created a Django RESTful API with JWT as authentication method, but unable to pass the token as headers using angularJS.

I think there is no error on my API, since I used the token I acquired by this script and tested it in Postman:
[image]

my JWT token authentication script is here:

```
 // Uses http.get() to load data from a single API endpoint
  list() {
    return this.http.get('api/', this.getHttpOptions());
  }

// helper function to build the HTTP headers
  getHttpOptions() {
    return {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': 'JWT ' + this._userService.token
      })
    };
  }
```

I tried using `http.get()` here. Thanks in advance!

the error will be like:

```
401 (Unauthorized)
```

Comment: are you seeing the header in the network request to api/ ?

Comment: I am having the same issue using Django rest framework Token and Ionic3. The headers appear to be set in the request, **Access-Control-Request-Headers 
authorization,content-type**. When i manually resend the request in firefox with the header as, **Authorization: Token xxxmyaccesstokenxxx** it succeeds which leads me to believe that Ionic/Angular is not setting the token in a way Django can access it.

Comment: Hi @J.ward thanks for your reminds, I have followed https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35760943/how-can-i-enable-cors-on-django-rest-framework this tutorial to set my backend, for the front end, I set the Access-Control-Request-Headers, but it still doesn't work. I don't know which part went wrong, if the API can be accessed by Postman, does that means my API is correct?

Comment: Hi @hsbzzhz, i just figured out what was wrong today. Django loads its middlewares sequentially and CORS middleware must be near the top for it to be applied correctly throughout the app. I spent far too long figuring that out. I had already set CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True in my app so it wasnt that for me but if some poor soul ever reads hopefully it saves them a few days of hair pulling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks guys, 
I found the problem is about CORS, My solutions are here, there are two approaches to solve this problem, one is add 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*' to your http request, sometimes you need add more. Another answer is add CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST = 'localhost:4200', in your backend.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OIbndrrUYiY

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
list() {
return this.http.get('api/', { this.getHttpOptions() });  
}

getHttpOptions() {
  const headers = new HttpHeaders({
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Authorization': 'JWT ' + this._userService.token
  }); 
   return headers;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I tried in this way:     return this.http.get(api/', {headers : this.getHttpOptions() });, but still doesn't work, same error code 401. I doubt the page hasn't refresh after I log in successful

Comment: Sorry that  didn't work.  That's almost exactly the code I use and it work fine for me.  Strange

Answer (score 0):

Same issue on JWT for CakePHP3, and follow header slove it, may it is helpful.

```
this.http.get('api/', { headers: new HttpHeaders({
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Authorization': 'JWT ' + this._userService.token,
    'Authenticationtoken': 'JWT ' + this._userService.token
}) });
```