# Cross-Origin Request Blocked - Using Axios and Django REST

Tags: django-rest-framework, axios

I am trying to make a GET request in my application that is being served locally (port 8080) using on a node server. I am using Axios to make the request to a django REST server that is also being served locally (port 8000).

My request looks like:

```
axios.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/recipes/',{headers: {"Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"}})
```

On the Django side, I've included these in my middleware

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
]
```

and this in my installed apps:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'corsheaders',
]
```

And included this setting:

```
CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True
```

But I'm still getting a CORS error:

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://127.0.0.1:8000/recipes/. (Reason: missing token ‘access-control-allow-origin’ in CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Headers’ from CORS preflight channel).
```

Any idea what I'm missing?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35760943/how-can-i-enable-cors-on-django-rest-framework

Answer (score 3):

I figured it out.

I needed to remove:

```
{headers: {"Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"}
```

from the request. Apparently that header should only be part of the response.

After removing, everything is working.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an axios instance, putting the domain part of your url in baseUrl, and the rest in get, is that simple.

```
var instance = axios.create({
    baseURL: "http://localhost:8088"
  });

  instance.get(url)
      .then(function(response) { 
    })
```