# ReactJS + Axios "Uncaught (in promise) Error: Network Error" | "Uncaught TypeError: response.data is undefined"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, jwt

newbie here :)

I am trying to learn about JWT Authentication following a tutorial with Django back end and React. https://hackernoon.com/110percent-complete-jwt-authentication-with-django-and-react-2020-iejq34ta .

I solve many unexpected errors on this tutorial before with online searching, but now i can't find a solution.

I am on first steps to use Axios for requests and tokens, from tutorial :

" *We want to use Axios for: POSTing to /api/user/create/ to create a userPOSTing to /api/token/obtain/ to login a user and obtain a JWT token pairPOSTing to /api/token/refresh/ to refresh the JWT token pairGETting from the protected /api/hello/ to see what the backend secretly has to say* "

The expected behavior based on the tutorial is on (Image 1) :

[The expected behavior : Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k8zFd.png)

But after `npm run build` command `python manage.py runserver` command, i am trying to Log In in the system and i got this error on firefox console (Image 2)

[Error on firefox console : Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7qzon.png)

Also, on Django console i got `"OPTIONS /api/token/obtain/ HTTP/1.1" 200 372`  instead of `"POST /api/token/obtain/ HTTP/1.1" 200 491`.

The files i used for this section of tutorial is :

```
// djsr/frontend/src/axiosApi.js

import axios from 'axios'

const axiosInstance = axios.create({
    baseURL: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/',
    timeout: 5000,
    headers: {
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
        'Authorization': "JWT " + localStorage.getItem('access_token'),
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'accept': 'application/json'
    }
});

export default axiosInstance;
```

**Note* : I found online that I should put `'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'` on headers in `djsr/frontend/src/axiosApi.js` but nothing happens with this.*

and the :

```
// djsr/frontend/src/components/login.js

    import React, { Component } from "react";
    import axiosInstance from "../axiosApi";
    
    class Login extends Component {
        constructor(props) {
            super(props);
            this.state = {username: "", password: ""};
    
            this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
            this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
        }
    
        handleChange(event) {
            this.setState({[event.target.name]: event.target.value});
        }
    
        handleSubmit(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            try {
                
                const response = axiosInstance.post('/token/obtain/', {
                    username: this.state.username,
                    password: this.state.password
                });
                axiosInstance.defaults.headers['Authorization'] = "JWT " + response.data.access;
                localStorage.setItem('access_token', response.data.access);
                localStorage.setItem('refresh_token', response.data.refresh);
                return data;
            } catch (error) {
                throw error;
            }
        }
    
        render() {
            return (
                <div>
                    Login
                    <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                        <label>
                            Username:
                            <input name="username" type="text" value={this.state.username} onChange={this.handleChange}/>
                        </label>
                        <label>
                            Password:
                            <input name="password" type="password" value={this.state.password} onChange={this.handleChange}/>
                        </label>
                        <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
                    </form>
                </div>
            )
        }
    }
    export default Login;
```

*P.S : I really hope for a solution, to finish this tutorial, to be happy :)
Thank you all for your time and for help!!*

Comment: Access-Control-Allow-Origin header must be set on the server side

Comment: You need to enable CORS on the Django side with something like this http://www.srikanthtechnologies.com/blog/python/enable_cors_for_django.aspx also the OPTIONS is a pre-flight check basically testing if you can make the request, so your Django server needs to respond to that allowing CORS requests

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK guys I figured it out.
Help from this post : [THE SOLUTION](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53577134/cross-origin-request-blocked-using-axios-and-django-rest)

I need to enable corsheaders in Django.

First off all, I install corsheaders with `pip install django-cors-headers`, and add in `settings.py` :

In middleware :

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
]
```

In installed apps :

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'corsheaders',
]
```

And include this setting :

```
CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True
```

And remove from `axiosApi.js` the :

```
{headers: {"Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"}
```

Also, https://stackoverflow.com/a/62824251/10182785 this answer was helpful for me.

Answer (score 0):

Well i got the same error, for me i used a proxy in my package.json file to my server port and in the server file i allowed the cross origin resource sharing(cors)
Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

You should check some details

```
async function handleSubmit(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  //Your baseURL: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/', if you URL is /token/obtain/ then final url http://127.0.0.1:8000/api//token/obtain/
  axiosInstance
    .post("token/obtain/", {
      username: this.state.username,
      password: this.state.password,
    })
    .then((response) => {
      console.log(response.data);
      console.log(response.status);
      console.log(response.statusText);
      console.log(response.headers);
      console.log(response.config);
      if (response.status === 200) {
        localStorage.setItem("access_token", response.data.access);
        localStorage.setItem("refresh_token", response.data.refresh);
      }
    })
    .catch((err) => console.error(err));
}
```

Comment: Your answer is very helpful to get rid of ´“Uncaught TypeError: response.data is undefined”´ but still ´"cors access-control-allow-headers missing"´ error. I found the solution for. I wrote the solution on my answer. THANK YOU!

Answer (score -1):

// First step

`npm i cors`

// Second step - in your node js

const cors = require('cors');

app.use(cors());

Comment: OP is using Django (Python), not Express (Node.js)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).