# How to have a local instance or React hit a local instance of Django

Tags: django, reactjs, django-rest-framework

I have a django api (djangorestframekwork, django2.1, python 3.6) that I run locally - `http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/cards/b361d7e2-6873-4890-8f87-702d9c89c5ad`. This api seems to work well. I can hit it via the web api or use curl/requests to add to or view the database.

Now, I want to be able to have my React project hit this api. I can have my react project hit a different api and it returns the data, but when I replace that URI with my own URI it breaks.

App.js - there is one line commented out. Switch that out with the other to switch between the public and private api.

```
import React from 'react'
import keyforge from '../api/keyforge'
import localhost from '../api/localhost'
import SearchBar from './SearchBar'

class App extends React.Component {

    onSearchSubmit = async (term) => {    
    const response = await localhost.get("api/cards/" + term)
    //const response = await keyforge.get("api/decks/" + term)
    console.log(response)
  }

  render () {
    return (<div className='ui container'>
      <SearchBar onSubmit={this.onSearchSubmit} />
    </div>)
  }
}
export default App
```

keyforge.js - this one works!

```
import axios from 'axios'
const proxyurl = 'https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/'
const url = 'https://www.keyforgegame.com/'    
export default axios.create({
  // baseURL: 'https://www.keyforgegame.com/api/decks/'
  baseURL: proxyurl + url
})
```

localhost.js - this one does not work

```
import axios from 'axios'

const proxyurl = 'https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/'
const url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/'

export default axios.create({
  baseURL: proxyurl + url
})
```

Error message:

```
GET https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/cards/b361d7e2-6873-4890-8f87-702d9c89c5ad 404 (Not Found)

Uncaught (in promise) Error: Request failed with status code 404
at createError (createError.js:17)
at settle (settle.js:19)
at XMLHttpRequest.handleLoad (xhr.js:78)
```

On my computer - `http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/cards/b361d7e2-6873-4890-8f87-702d9c89c5ad` takes me to the Django api page for that specifc element. If I get rid of the `cors-anywhere url` I get this error -

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/cards/b361d7e2-6873-4890-8f87-702d9c89c5ad' from origin 'http://127.0.0.1:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

I have this `cors-anywhere` url prepended to it to solve the  `No Access-Control-Allow-Origin` error that you see when I hit this to the public api. Since I get the same error when I hit my own private api, I am using the same solution (e.g. the `cors-anywhere` url prepeneded to my url.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably because you didn't enabled `CORS` on your django rest project. There is a tool called `django-cors-headers`, Install it via `pip install django-cors-headers`, add it's midlleware and enable it in your `settings.py` file.

```
pip install django-cors-headers
```

then add it to installed apps:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
...
'corsheaders',
...
)
```

add it's middleware:

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
...
'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
...
)
```

and finally add this variable in the end of your `settings.py` file:

```
CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True
```

Find out more about it here: [django-cors-headers on github](https://github.com/ottoyiu/django-cors-headers/)

Answer (score 1):

Your `keyforge.js` file works because you're hitting an already hosted website which has CORS enabled at it's backend as well. You need to add CORS at your Django backend as well. From what you've said, it seems that you've only added it at the front end. Probably something like could help you.

[How can I enable CORS on Django REST Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35760943/how-can-i-enable-cors-on-django-rest-framework)