# How to solve 'TypeError: Network request failed' in React Native?

Tags: reactjs, laravel, api, react-native, expo

**Environment**

I'm developing a mobile app with React Native and Expo.

Also, developing api with Laravel that is in my local environment. (http://localhost:8000/)

This app is working on Expo client app.

**What I'm trying to do**

I wanna get datas from api.

**Code**

App.js

```js
componentDidMount() {
  return fetch('http://localhost:8000/api/test')
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((responseJson) => {
      console.log(responseJson);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.error(error);
    });
}
```

**Error**

> TypeError: Network request failed

**Expo version**

3.22.3

I would appreciate it if you could give me any advice.

Comment: Maybe `https` instead?

Comment: @高鵬翔 Thanks. I think it should be ```http```.

Comment: iOS won't make api calls to http, there are some additional steps required to make that happen, google it or switch to https

Answer (score 8):

you should not use `http://localhost:8000` for your base URL, please use your IP Address.

if you use Macbook, you can find the IP in System Preferences > Network

[image: find ip]

then use `fetch('http://172.20.10.5:8000/api/test')` in your react native app.

if my base URL when access via browser is `http://172.20.10.5:8000/mysite/api/test` you need fetch in react native `fetch('http://172.20.10.5:8000/mysite/api/test')`

basically, android & ios did not allow request using HTTP, you need to do something below to allow HTTP connection instead of HTTPS.

### android

and then add android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" in your Android manifest `android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml`

### iphone

add this in info.plist

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
        <true/>
        <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
        <dict>
            <key>localhost</key>
            <dict>
                <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
                <true/>
            </dict>
        </dict>
    </dict>
```

Comment: Thank you. I changed to my IP address, but it didn't work :(

Comment: can i know your full URL in your Browser/Postman for accessing the datas?

also make sure your computer (server) and your device must be on the same local network. Wifi and lan shares the same network.

Comment: My full URL is http://localhost:8000/api/test. My computer and iPhone are on the same network.

Comment: add android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" in Android manifest

Comment: Is that related? I'm using expo client app on iPhone.

Comment: yeah it is related, check my edited answer and let me know if it works.

Comment: Android manifest and info.plist don't exist cuz I'm using expo :(

Comment: unfortunetaley, expo blocked HTTP request. see https://forums.expo.io/t/how-to-enable-ios-http-requests/1794

Comment: what you can do is enable HTTPS in localhost on your laravel project, you can refer to https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/use-httpslocalhost8000-to-start-server

Comment: Thank you for helping me. I'll let you know when something goes well.

Answer (score 5):

Try using http://10.0.2.2/api/test

Emulators has special IP Address for localhost connection.

[Check this table out](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0V7sV.png)

Read about it [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-networking.html)

Answer (score -1):

if after this it not work, disable you firewall

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).