# TypeError: Network request failed (using ReactNative and Django)

Tags: android, django, react-native, fetch-api

I'm developing a mobile app with React Native, and have a REST API in Django at the backend. I want to make a POST request from the app to my API.

**Code**

```
function sendDpi() {
const requestOptions = {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    Accept: 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({
    dpi: imageDpi,
  }),
};
fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8000/', requestOptions)
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => console.log(data))
  .catch(error => {
    console.log(error);
  });
}
```

When `sendDpi()` is called by my app, I get `[TypeError: Network request failed]`. 
`127.0.0.1:8000` is where my Django app is running. I've tried using my IP address (as pointed out by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62946640/9864448) answer) as well. 
I've also modified `android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml` to include `android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The suggestion made before was great except the URL needed should be `http://10.0.2.2:8000` instead of `http://10.0.2.2/8000`

Answer (score 2):

I think `127.0.0.1:8000` is also localhost. You need to find your external ip address if you use a physical device to test from.

I you test from android emulator you can just use http://10.0.2.2/8000.

Also try to make it work with http first. You might not have a valid SSL certificate. With invalid SSL certificate you also get `[TypeError: Network request failed]`

Comment: I get the same error when I use http://10.0.2.2/8000 or my external IP address. What did you mean by 'make it work with HTTP first'?

Comment: If your Django app is serving ‘https://‘ and you don’t have a valid ssl certificate then you’ll will get the error. Can the Django app serve as ‘http://‘?

Comment: yeah, it can serve as 'http://'

Comment: @protonpasta you still have the problem? Could it be a firewall problem? You could try to serve your django app through ngrok: https://www.twilio.com/blog/expose-local-django-server-to-internet-using-ngrok.

Answer (score 0):

In **Django** settings.py

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['192.168.1.7']
```

Starting **Django** shell

```
python manage.py runserver 192.168.1.7:8000
```

Check link on browser if working

```
http://192.168.1.7:8000/polls/articles/
```

In **React**/**ReactNative** project, see result on shell

```
useEffect(() => {
        fetch('http://192.168.1.7:8000/polls/articles/',
        {method: 'GET'})
        .then(resp => resp.json())
        .then(data => {
            console.log(data)
        })
        .catch(error => console.log(error))
    }, [])
```