# (React Native and Django) TypeError: Network request failed

Tags: django, react-native, django-rest-framework

I'm developing a mobile app with the concept of using react-native as front end and Django as back-end. I'm actually following this series of tutorials: [Javascript Fetch - Communicating between a ReactNative App and Django REST API](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AYA5K5NYBAc) but when I got to the part where I have to use a fetch method I am getting a **TypeError: Network request failed**.

Here is a snippet of my code:

```
const [ domain, setDomain ] = useState("http://10.0.2.2:8000")

function initAppSettings(){
        console.log(domain)
        fetch(`$(domain)/api/v1.0/app/settings`, {
            method: 'GET',
        })
        .then (result => {
            if (result.ok) {
                return result.json()
            } else {
                throw result.json()
            }
        })
        .then (JSON => {
            console.log(JSON)
        })
        .catch (error => {
            console.log(error)
        })
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        initAppSettings()
    }, [])
```

I have already tried editing the **AndroidManifest.xml** by adding
`android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"`. I also tried using **my own ipv4 address** in my Django runserver but still failed to access it.
I have the same question as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70300538/typeerror-network-request-failed-using-reactnative-and-django) but the answer here do not solve my issue.

Comment: Use the same ipv4 address in the domain from react native

Comment: @BishalRaEe sorry I'm a newbie, how can I do that? I'm using windows btw. Thanks!

Comment: use the same ip addres that you used to run django server in the domain state