# CORS error during fetch onComponentDidMount in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, django, reactjs

**i am getting empty page as output while fetching api data in reactjs.**

Repo: https://github.com/te3t0/building-small-blog

i am probably new to reactjs, i am getting an empty page even data are fetched perfectly. it would be great if anybody could help me where i am doing thing wrong. thank you so much in advance.

endpoint_url : http://localhost:8000/api/blog_list

api-data:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "url": "http://localhost:8000/api/blog_detail/brown",
        "title": "brown",
        "slug": "brown",
        "image": "http://localhost:8000/media/blog/image_2.jpg",
        "description": "",
        "created_on": "2020-05-08T15:20:53Z",
        "status": true,
        "category": [
            1
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "url": "http://localhost:8000/api/blog_detail/black",
        "title": "black",
        "slug": "black",
        "image": "http://localhost:8000/media/blog/loc.png",
        "description": "",
        "created_on": "2020-05-08T17:14:31Z",
        "status": true,
        "category": [
            2
        ]
    }
]
```

./src/Base.js

```
export default class App extends Component{

  state = {
    bloglist:[]
  };

  componentDidMount(){
    this.fetchData()
  }

  fetchData = async () => {
    try{
      const response = await fetch("http://localhost:8000/api/blog_list");
      const jsonResponse = await response.json()
      this.setState({bloglist:jsonResponse})
    }
    catch(error){
      console.log(error)
    }
  }

  render(){
    const {bloglist} = this.state
    if(!bloglist){
      return (
        <div>
          <h1>loading...</h1>
        </div>
      )
    }

    return (
      {
        bloglist.map(bloglist => (
          <h3 class="mb-2">
            <a href="single.html">{bloglist.title}</a>
          </h3>
          <p class="mb-4">{bloglist.description}</p>
          ))
      }
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: add a link to your repository

Comment: What do you mean by "an empty page"?

Comment: here is my repository--> https://github.com/te3t0/building-small-blog   @DenisTsoi

Comment: usually i am getting an blank page while fetching data. i am not getting result as expected.  @GalAbra

Comment: the app is getting a `GET http://localhost:8000/api/blog_list net::ERR_FAILED` - from `Access to fetch at 'http://localhost:8000/api/blog_list' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.`

Comment: it means you dont have CORS enabled for the app - hence the fetch is failing

Comment: img going to add a PR for you

Comment: https://github.com/te3t0/building-small-blog/pull/1

Comment: try to upvote as well - ive upvoted your other questions so that should help

Comment: now it's showing me error at,  "{bloglist.map(bloglist => "  Syntax error: Unexpected token, expected. @DenisTsoi

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213470/discussion-between-denis-tsoi-and-bounty).

Comment: hey there, please take a look at chatbox. @DenisTsoi

Comment: try to upvote the answer below - thanks

Comment: @bounty upvote if you can - thx

Comment: hey there... could you take a look at this link? --> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61856949/how-to-fetch-pagination-effect-in-reactjs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since this is a first post for you - there's a few things that didn't go well in terms of debugging the problem.

For larger problems like the one you asked - it helps to provide the error
from the developer console tools as well as the remote repository source.

e.g.

> `GET http://localhost:8000/api/blog_list net::ERR_FAILED`
>
> `'http://localhost:8000/api/blog_list' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled`

From there - by including the [remote repository](https://github.com/te3t0/building-small-blog) - I was able to find out more via [How can I enable CORS on Django REST Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35760943/how-can-i-enable-cors-on-django-rest-framework)

Which led to the following answer:

1. `pip install django-cors-headers`
2. add installed apps

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    ...
    'corsheaders',
    ...
)
```

3. add middleware

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    ...
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',  
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',  
    ...
)

CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True # If this is used then `CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST` will not have any effect
CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = True
CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST = [
    'http://localhost:3000',
] # If this is used, then not need to use `CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True`
CORS_ORIGIN_REGEX_WHITELIST = [
    'http://localhost:3000',
]
```