# how to fetch pagination effect in ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

As per below `image`, there is pagination set. How to set pagination effect whenever user click on `page no.`

here below is my src code, but output is getting `null` value while fetching the data.

[image]

end-point url: `http://localhost:8000/api/blog_list?page=`

`./src/BlogList.js`

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);


    this.state = {
      value: "",
      response: "",
    };


  function pageClick(e){
    this.setState({value: e.target.innerHTML});
    this.fetchData();

  };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.fetchData();
  }

  fetchData = async () => {

    try {
      const response = await fetch(
        `http://localhost:8000/api/blog_list?page=${this.state.value}`
      );
      const JsonResponse = await response.json();
      this.setState({ response: JsonResponse });
    } 
    catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };


  render() {
    const { response } = this.state;

    if (!response) {
      return "Loading...";
    }

    return (
      <div>
        {response.results.map((response) =>(

            <div class="col-md-12">

                    <img src={response.image} className="App-logo"/>

                    <div class="text text-2 pl-md-4">

                      <h3 class="mb-2">{response.title}</h3>

                    </div>
            </div>
        ))}

        <div class="col">
            <ul>
              <li><a href="#">&lt;</a></li>
              <li class="active"><span onClick={this.pageClick}>1</span></li>
              <li><a href="#" onClick={this.pageClick}>2</a></li>
              <li><a href="#" onClick={this.pageClick}>3</a></li>
              <li><a href="#" onClick={this.pageClick}>4</a></li>
              <li><a href="#" onClick={this.pageClick}>5</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">&gt;</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>

      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: `setState` is potentially asynchronous. When the subsequent action depends on `this.state` having the updated value, you should put it in a callback as the second argument to `setState`: `this.setState({value: e.target.innerHTML}, () => this.fetchData()) ;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of issues

1. the `pageClick` should not be defined inside the `constructor`, but should be a method of the class.
2. `setState` is asynchronous, so you should use the additional argument which is a callback called after the state has been set
3. it would be a better approach to actually pass the page you want to set directly in the `pageClick` instead of reading the `innerHTML` (*although the error has nothing to do with this*)
4. you should initialize (*for clarity, not an error*) the `value` to an actual page number.
5. also another good idea is to not shadow variable names. So, rename either the outer `response` (*in the state*) or the individual `response` when you map over the `results`.

```js
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);


    this.state = {
      value: 1,
      responses: "",
    };

  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.fetchData();
  }

  pageClick = (page) => {
    this.setState({value: page}, this.fetchData);
  };

  fetchData = async () => {

    try {
      const response = await fetch(
        `http://localhost:8000/api/blog_list?page=${this.state.value}`
      );
      const JsonResponse = await response.json();
      this.setState({ responses: JsonResponse });
    } 
    catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };


  render() {
    const { responses } = this.state;

    if (!responses) {
      return "Loading...";
    }

    return (
      <div>
        {responses.results.map((response) =>(
            <div class="col-md-12">
                    <img src={response.image} className="App-logo"/>
                    <div class="text text-2 pl-md-4">
                      <h3 class="mb-2">{response.title}</h3>
                    </div>
            </div>
        ))}
        <div class="col">
            <ul>
              <li><a href="#">&lt;</a></li>
              <li class="active"><span onClick={() => this.pageClick(1)}>1</span></li>
              <li><a href="#" onClick={() => this.pageClick(2)}>2</a></li>
              <li><a href="#" onClick={() => this.pageClick(3)}>3</a></li>
              <li><a href="#" onClick={() => this.pageClick(4)}>4</a></li>
              <li><a href="#" onClick={() => this.pageClick(5)}>5</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">&gt;</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: hey there.... please take a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62701259/how-to-use-search-effect-in-reactjs    .  Hopefully you can help me here. Thanxx!!

Answer (score 0):

Try Something like this:

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      response: ""
    };
  }

  pageClick(e) {
    this.fetchData(+e.target.innerHTML);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.fetchData();
  }

  fetchData = async (pageNo = 0) => {
    try {
      const response = await fetch(
        `http://localhost:8000/api/blog_list?page=${pageNo}`
      );
      const JsonResponse = await response.json();
      this.setState({ response: JsonResponse });
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };

  render() {
    const { response } = this.state;

    if (!response) {
      return "Loading...";
    }

    return (
      <div>
        ... your html
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```