# How to solve CORS with Django and VueJs?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, vue.js, vuejs2

How to solve CORS with Django and VueJs?

I have made some settings, but I can't solve it.

Could anyone help?

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
   ....

    'rest_framework',
    'corsheaders',
...
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsPostCsrfMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True
CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = True
```

Axios

```
axios.defaults.headers = { 'Accept': 'application/json', 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }
```

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://api.novosite.com/api/token' from
> origin 'https://novosite.vip' has been blocked by CORS policy:
> Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
> 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
> resource.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not used to working with django but I do use flask with CORS.
Here's a link to another thread which might help : [How can I enable CORS on Django REST Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35760943/how-can-i-enable-cors-on-django-rest-framework)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I was using `django-cors-headers` and followed their instructions to the T.

The cause of my issue was on the client-side. The server URL I used, namely `localhost:8000`, didn't contain the protocol.
When I changed it to `http://localhost:8000` it worked.