# Django JQuery autocomplete not working - nothing showing up, but API URL works

Tags: jquery, django, autocomplete

I have tried to implement autocomplete exactly as this tutorial shows: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-oLVZp1NQVE

Here is the tutorial code, which is very similar to what I have here: https://github.com/akjasim/cb_dj_autocomplete

However, it is not working for me. The API url works, but nothing populates in the field, i.e. there is no autocomplete that shows up. What could I be doing wrong? I'm using yarn and yarn build and have collected static, but still does not work.

Here is the jquery:

```
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(function () {
            $("#product").autocomplete({
                source: '{% url 'autocomplete' %}',
                minLength: 2
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Here is the html:

```
<title>Autocomplete</title>
</head>
<body>
<form>
    <label for="product">Product</label>
    <input type="text" name="product" id="product">
</form>
```

Here is the views:

```
def autocomplete(request):
    if 'term' in request.GET:
        qs = Model.objects.filter(title__icontains=request.GET.get('term'))
        titles = list()
        for product in qs:
            titles.append(product.title)
        # titles = [product.title for product in qs]
        return JsonResponse(titles, safe=False)
    return render(request, 'file_for_viewing.html')
```

Then here is the URL:

```
path('autocomplete',views.autocomplete, name='autocomplete'),
```

Even when source is a list, autocomplete not working:

```
source: '['chicago', 'new york',...,'']
```

So the error is the request is getting canceled, because `XMLHttpRequest cannot load XXX due to access control checks.`

Comment: why don't you use JQuery's default autocomplete? It works like a charm and you're already loading the JQuery libraries. https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

Comment: could you post a screenshot of the browser inspect tool,in the network tab,about the ajax request

Answer (score 1):

I tried your code and it is working fine with some corrections. I haven't faced any issues with the Access Control Headers.. If you haven't changed the code, the changes I made are.

1. The Model is Product

   ```
   qs = Product.objects.filter(title__icontains=request.GET.get('term'))
   ```
2. When testing with a list as source, source should be an array..

   ```
   source: ['chicago', 'new york',]
   ```

If you are still facing issues with access control. setup django-cors-headers.

There are already a ton of answers there on stackoverflow about setting up django-cors-headers..

1. [Django-cors-headers](https://github.com/adamchainz/django-cors-headers)
2. [How can I enable CORS on Django REST Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35760943/how-can-i-enable-cors-on-django-rest-framework)