# Fixing CORS error issue axois.get MissingAllowOriginHeader

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, apache, axios, cors

Okay so:
I'm running a LightSail instance at [www.gethatext.com](https://gethatext.com).

- FrontEnd - React, BackEnd - Django

On the homepage, I'm making 2 get requests to the Django server.

> It is important to say that both Django & React are being served in the apache server.

- **.conf file of apache** (http & https)

  ProxyPass /api http://localhost:8000.    # Django.
  ProxyPassReverse /api http://localhost:8000 # Django.
  ProxyPass / http://localhost:3000/.     # React.
  ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:3000/. #React.

So I investigated and read that i need to add the following to the .conf file in either `<Directory>, <Location> or <VirtualHost>`. **and so I did (and restarted all services of source).**

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
   Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
</IfModule>
```

BUT it did not help.

[image: Devtools Network]

But when I'm making the same request from POSTMAN in my computer I get a the expected response (After running from the instance terminal `python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000`)

[image: POSTMAN]

I Also added https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com to my request
So it looked like:

```
axois.get("https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://gethatext.com/api/account/quantity/")....
```

and surprisingly **IT WORKED.**.
***But** it doesn't feel like a good practice and also in terms of data privacy*.

So I wonder what is it the problem here?

Is it related to that, that Django and React are both served in the same apache service?

Also add to axois header:

- "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"

But with no luck

Browser console error:
[image: Browser Error]

Cheers guys & Thanks in advnace.

Comment: Did you install django-cors on your project? if you didn't it yet, please check this `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35760943/how-can-i-enable-cors-on-django-rest-framework`

Comment: Yes I have, My Django project has corsheaders in the INSTALLED_APPS

Comment: Please share broswer console error.

Comment: added as final image

Comment: Please share allows_host from setting.py and run cmd.

Comment: when you run project "python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0"

Comment: The ALLOWED_HOSTS is assigned to all  ( "*" ) other wise I wold not get response from POSTMAN

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235627/discussion-between-forest-1-and-ben-koren-kruiger).

Comment: `https://medium.com/@zoltankohalmy/react-and-django-57f949b0f012` Please check this.

Comment: dont think it is relevant because it uses NGINX

Answer (score -1):

So the solution for this one was
Adding:

- "proxy" : "https:my-domain.com".
  to the package.json and in the axios requests.

  axios.get("/upload/quantity/").then()...
  And it worked