# Ajax in django doesnt work, no error and nothing happens

Tags: javascript, python, django, ajax

Solution:
My mistake was that the url attribute doesn't just add the string given to 127.0.0.1 but to the current url, and so the url for the Like view was supposed to be 127.0.0.1/article/article_id/like-article-commm

I wrote a django app that has articles and im trying to add a like functionality, I added the code in the bottom and nothing happens. No error just nothing in the database or the html code changes. Any idea what is the problem?

The relevent part of the html/javascript code:

```
    <head>
            <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js" integrity="sha256-WpOohJOqMqqyKL9FccASB9O0KwACQJpFTUBLTYOVvVU=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        </head>

        <button id='like-button' color = 'black'> Like </button>

<script type="text/javascript"> 
$('#like-button').click(function(){ 
var article_id = '{{ article.id }}';
var user_id = '{{ user.id }}';
var like_dislike = True;

$.ajax( 
{ 
    type:"GET",
    url: "like-article-commm",
    data:{ 
             article_id: article_id,
             user_id: user_id,
             like_dislike: like_dislike
}, 
success: function( data ) 
{ 
    $('#like-button').css('color', 'blue'); } }) });
</script>

The like-article-comm View:
```

```
def Like_Article_View(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        article_id = int(request.GET['article_id'])
        likedarticle = Article.objects.get(id = article_id)
        
        user_liked_id = int(request.GET['user_id'])
        userliked = User.objects.get(id = user_liked_id)

        like_dislike_0 = request.GET['like_dislike']

        like_object_list = Like_Article.objects.filter(article_liked = likedarticle, user_liked = userliked)

        if like_object_list.count() > 0:
            existing_like = like_object_list.filter()
            if existing_like.like_dislike == like_dislike_0:
                return HttpResponse('success')
            existing_like.like_dislike = like_dislike_0
            existing_like.save()




        like_new_object= Like_Article(article_liked=likedarticle, user_liked=userliked, like_dislike=like_dislike_0)
        like_new_object.save()

        return HttpResponse('success')
    else:
        return HttpResponse("unsuccesful")
```

urls.py file:

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views
from .views import ArticleListView, ArticleDetailView, ArticleCreateView, ArticleUpdateView, ArticleDeleteView

urlpatterns = [
    path('', ArticleListView.as_view(), name="home-comm"),
    path('article/<int:pk>/', ArticleDetailView.as_view(), name="article-comm"),
    path('like_article/', views.Like_Article_View, name='like-article-commm'),
]
```

I can add like objects to the database manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

--update--
After some discussion, we figure out that frontend ajax is not communicating with the backend properly. With **chrome devtools** we managed to pin point where the issue lies.

have you enabled CORS cross site resource sharing?

Comment: I dont know what that is, so probably not. How to check if it is enabeld and how to enabel it?

Comment: sorry i am not able to make clarification under your post thus i answer your question with another question. back to your question i think you can refer to this question [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35760943/how-can-i-enable-cors-on-django-rest-framework) as a starter

Comment: to put it in simple terms, django is serving at port say, 5000 (i work with flask another python web framework so not really sure about django), but your browser making async request from a different port / origin, it could be a malicious request to your server, so implicitly almost every web framework disabled CORS.

Comment: I added CORS however it didn't solve the problem

Comment: can you show me your console log? you can access it from chrome dev tools.

Comment: also i think you should use a post request instead as you are making changes to the backend.

Comment: your ajax address should be 127.0.0.1:5000/like-article-commm or localhost:5000/like-article-commm instead

Comment: jquery-3.4.1.js:9837 GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/article/3/like-article-commm?article_id=7&user_id=2 404 (Not Found)

Comment: This is the console log when the button is pressed

Comment: shouldnt it be posted to the "like_article" endpoint instead?

Comment: when i first bring up CORS i am assuming your frontend ajax is able to communicate with your backend django. however right now your issues here is your frontend ajax is not able to communicate with the correct endpoint.

Comment: Thanks it finally worked, following your idea of checking the consule log I managed to pinpoint the - insane amount of -  problems

Comment: well i would appreciate if you accept my answer such that i can comment directly under people's question next time haha.

Comment: @mushcatshiro You should edit and update your answer with the actual solution.