# How to setup the url of the backend site on react build for production

Tags: reactjs

When the site is running on the development way, "npm start", the backend url used is from the proxy at the package.json.

When i go for the production way "npm build", the backend url is not used from package.json, because that proxy is only for development.

I would like some help to understant how to configure that backend url, i am using the same url for both development and production.

In the configuration file .package.json:

```
{
  "name": "mysite_frontend_v1",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "proxy": "https://api.mysite.com",
...
}
```

And then created a file .env :

```
REACT_APP_API_URI = 'https://api.mysite.com'
```

the api.js file :

```
function request(path, { data = null, token = null, method = 'GET' }) {
  return fetch(path, {
    method,
    headers: {
      Authorization: token ? `Token ${token}` : '',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
    body: method !== 'GET' && method !== 'DELETE' ? JSON.stringify(data) : null,
  })
    .then((response) => {
      // If it is success
      if (response.ok) {
        if (method === 'DELETE') {
          // If delete, nothing return
          return true;
        }
        return response.json();
      }

      // Otherwise, if there are errors
      return response
        .json()
        .then((json) => {
          // Handle JSON error, response by the server
          if (response.status === 400) {
            const errors = Object.keys(json).map((k) => `${json[k].join(' ')}`);
            throw new Error(errors.join(' '));
          }
          throw new Error(JSON.stringify(json));
        })
        .catch((e) => {
          throw new Error(e);
        });
    })
    .catch((e) => {
      // Handle all errors
      toast(e.message, { type: 'error' });
    });
}

export function signIn(username, password) {
  return request('/auth/token/login/', {
    data: { username, password },
    method: 'POST',
  });
}

export function register(username, password) {
  return request('/auth/users/', {
    data: { username, password },
    method: 'POST',
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if that was the best solution, if someone finde a better one i would be glad with that.

So i started deleting the proxy:

```
{
  "name": "mysite_frontend_v1",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,

}
```

And then keep the .env file :

```
REACT_APP_API_URI = 'https://api.mysite.com'
```

added a const in the api.js file :

```
const base_url = process.env.REACT_APP_API_URI

function request(path, { data = null, token = null, method = 'GET' }) {
  return fetch( base_url + path, {
    method,
    headers: {
      Authorization: token ? `Token ${token}` : '',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
    body: method !== 'GET' && method !== 'DELETE' ? JSON.stringify(data) : null,
  })
    .then((response) => {
      // If it is success
      if (response.ok) {
        if (method === 'DELETE') {
          // If delete, nothing return
          return true;
        }
        return response.json();
      }

      // Otherwise, if there are errors
      return response
        .json()
        .then((json) => {
          // Handle JSON error, response by the server
          if (response.status === 400) {
            const errors = Object.keys(json).map((k) => `${json[k].join(' ')}`);
            throw new Error(errors.join(' '));
          }
          throw new Error(JSON.stringify(json));
        })
        .catch((e) => {
          throw new Error(e);
        });
    })
    .catch((e) => {
      // Handle all errors
      toast(e.message, { type: 'error' });
    });
}

export function signIn(username, password) {
  return request('/auth/token/login/', {
    data: { username, password },
    method: 'POST',
  });
}

...
```

but than i started to get issues with CORS, so it was needed to make changes in the backend, that was in django.

So i followed this answer for the CORS configuration.

[How can I enable CORS on Django REST Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35760943/how-can-i-enable-cors-on-django-rest-framework)

After that, all was working ok, both production and development, not using proxy any more in that case.

Answer (score 0):

The proxy feature isn't meant for production.
So, you must set host URL in .env file

Comment: Thanks for the answer, could you help me with that, in the question I show how is my .env file, but how do I call it in the react app?

Comment: Call .env variable like this : process.env.REACT_APP_API_URI