# how can I solve this error on angular app

Tags: django, angular

This error is showing after I keeps running ng serve --disable-host-check and have enable for all origin on python django rest framework
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'localhost:8000/supplier/' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome-extension, edge, chrome-untrusted, https, isolated-app.

Comment: you need to setup CORS in Django. its the browser that stops you. And it is a server issue. Just lookup CORS. and how to setup.

Comment: Hello! Hope this link help you! https://stackoverflow.com/a/35761088/13642816

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I enable CORS on Django REST Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35760943/how-can-i-enable-cors-on-django-rest-framework)