# Angular error with json API with python anywhere- has been blocked by CORS

Tags: django, angular, pythonanywhere, django-cors-headers

i want to access an api with angular. the api is hosted by pythonanywhere. When accessing the API I get the following error:

> Access to fetch at 'https://www.pythonanywhere.com/api/v0/user/myusername/cpu/?format=json' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

> data-analysis.component.ts:26 ERROR HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 504, statusText: 'Gateway Timeout', url: 'https://www.pythonanywhere.com/api/v0/user/StevoEs/cpu/?format=json', ok: false, …}

**python-anywhere.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable, throwError } from 'rxjs';


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class PythonAnywhereService {
  private host = 'www.pythonanywhere.com';
  private username = 'myUsername';
  private token = 'myToken';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}


  getCpuData(): Observable<any> {
    const headers = new HttpHeaders({
      'Authorization': `Token ${this.token}`
    });
    return this.http.get<any>(
      `https://${this.host}/api/v0/user/${this.username}/cpu/?format=json`,
      { headers }
    );
  }
}
```

**data-analyse.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { PythonAnywhereService } from '../../services/python-anywhere.service';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-data-analyse',
  template: `
  <div class="card text-center bg-dark">
    <div class="card-header">
      Server CPU auslastung!
    </div>
    <div class="card-body">
      <div *ngIf="cpuData">
        {{ cpuData }}
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  `
})
export class DataAnalysisComponent  implements OnInit {
  cpuData: any;

  constructor(private pythonAnywhereService: PythonAnywhereService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.pythonAnywhereService.getCpuData().subscribe(data => {
      this.cpuData = data;
    });
  }


}
```

I have read through the documentation on Angular. But I don't understand it. Searching in forums didn't help me either.

I have installed Django on pythonanywhere. There are some settings but I couldn't solve the problem there either.

I have censored the username and the token here.

Does anyone know what I can do?

**edit:**

i have tried everything i could think of. however, the errors do not change at all and i am getting stuck. here is my setting.py:

from pathlib import Path

````
# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'django-insecure-b70$%5snd)0k!hfliophl)0b%s^kypxu0wfv!znvmw&d!7^7&7'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']

CORS_ALLOW_ALL_ORIGINS: True

CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True

CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS = [
    "*",
    "https://myhomepage.de",
    "http://localhost:8080",
    "http://127.0.0.1:9000",
    "http://localhost:4200",
]


ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['StevoEs.pythonanywhere.com']

# Application definition

CORS_ALLOW_METHODS = [
    "DELETE",
    "GET",
    "OPTIONS",
    "PATCH",
    "POST",
    "PUT",
]

CORS_ALLOW_HEADERS = [
    "accept",
    "accept-encoding",
    "authorization",
    "content-type",
    "dnt",
    "origin",
    "user-agent",
    "x-csrftoken",
    "x-requested-with",
]


INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'corsheaders',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'mysite.urls'

CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS = [
    "*",
    "http://read.only.com",
    "http://change.allowed.com",
]

CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS = [
    "http://change.allowed.com",
]

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'mysite.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = 'static/'

# Default primary key field type
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/#default-auto-field

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'

# default static files settings for PythonAnywhere.
# see https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/DjangoStaticFiles for more info
MEDIA_ROOT = '/home/StevoEs/mysite/media'
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
STATIC_ROOT = '/home/StevoEs/mysite/static'
STATIC_URL = '/static/'```
````

Comment: You can't do anything from the Angular side, which is all you've shown us; you need to fix this in Django.

Comment: i added the other part of django.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a front-end (Angular) issue. You've been blocked by CORS. More details are available here: [CORS MOZILLA](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/http/cors) and the solution to your question is probably provided here: [SOLUTION](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35761088/4860179). I know it's not a much of an answer, but at this point I would just copy someone else. It's no point if I can just provide a link.

Comment: You need to fix it in your backend allowing "http://localhost:4200" or '*' in CORS policy. For production enviroment set CORS as your domain or subdomain

Comment: i have done all these things. somehow nothing helps. in the forums you read the same advice over and over again. only i can't get my problems to go away. the error messages don't change. no matter what i try.

there must be an error somewhere :/

Comment: @StevoEs Can you check your browser network tab and tell if CORS headers are present? It might be weird by you might also try and download browser extension to unblock CORS, and check if it helps. Sometimes playing on localhost environment can be tricky.

Comment: he is trying to download 3 files. All 3 files have 3 different errors.
File1. xhr
File 2 . fetch
File 3. preflight

and the header message is as follows:
message
: 
"Http failure response for https://www.pythonanywhere.com/api/v0/user/myUsername/cpu/?format=json: 504 Gateway Timeout".
my homepage is online. there you can see it in detail i hope. 
https://studenski.club/data
I hope this helps