# Django-cors-headers not working with Django and Vue

Tags: python, django, vue.js, cors, django-cors-headers

When I try to access my Django rest framework from the frontend I get this error and the data is not passed along

```
Access to fetch at 'http://localhost:8000/api/students' from origin 'http://localhost:5173' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
```

I tried using django-cors-headers and every setting for it that I could find online; absolutely nothing worked.

Here are the settings from my settings.py file (currently commented out)

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'rest_framework',
    'corsheaders',
    'students'
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'project.middleware.CustomCorsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]
# clickjacking not compatible with corsheaders?
CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True
# CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = True
# CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST = [
#     "http://localhost:8000",
#     "http://127.0.0.1:8000",
#     "http://localhost:5173",
#     "http://127.0.0.1:5173",
# ]
# CORS_ALLOW_HEADERS = ['*']
#
# CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS = [
#     "http://localhost:8000",
#     "http://127.0.0.1:8000",
#     "http://localhost:5173",
#     "http://127.0.0.1:5173",
# ]
```

I also tried using custom middleware that I found here on stack overflow.

```
class CustomCorsMiddleware:
    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response
        # One-time configuration and initialization.

    def __call__(self, request):
        # Code to be executed for each request before
        # the view (and later middleware) are called.

        response = self.get_response(request)
        response["Access-Control-Allow-Origin"] = "*"
        response["Access-Control-Allow-Headers"] = "*"

        # Code to be executed for each request/response after
        # the view is called.

        return response
```

I did not try to use the custom middleware and django-cors-headers together.

I must have spent at least a day on this nonsense. I'd really appreciate a working solution or at least a workaround!

PS: I am following this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7GWKv03Osek&t=189s He doesn't have the same problems that I am though.

Comment: What is the version of your django-cors-headers? I checked the documentation and the newest one uses CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS, but I'm not sure since I didn't test your code. I don't think clickjacking is the issue here.

Comment: I tried commenting out clickjacking with no luck. I followed the docs https://pypi.org/project/django-cors-headers/ instructions down to CORS_ALLOW_ALL_ORIGINS but it doesn't work. I downloaded it a couple weeks ago so I'm sure my version isn't outdated.

Comment: Have you tried placing    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware' at the last of your middleware? And I believe you have seen this from the CustomCorsMiddleware code but I'll put this here for documentation purpose:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35760943/how-can-i-enable-cors-on-django-rest-framework

Comment: Unfortunately placing it at the end doesn't work either. Thanks for the link, I hope some other custom middleware might solve my problem, even if the one I tried didn't help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clearing my browsing data in my browser made it work.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue but in my case, I was using angular..

In my case, I did not need to create custom middleware, using `corsheaders` only two settings was needed for it to work.

Firstly set the `corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware` below the session middleware.

Secondly, set `CORS_ALLOW_ALL_ORIGINS=True`

The version of `django-cors-headers` that seemed to work for me was `4.2.0`. Maybe you should try installing this specific version.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. It doesn't seem to work regardless of where I place it. If nothing else works I may have to try downgrading.